# Disable dropwizard's internal logging for a particular resource

Tags: java, dropwizard

I want to disable logging when a critical information is passed to a certain resource(URL).

Comment: What problem are you having with this?

Comment: i don't want to log IMP user info for everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the logging level on a per class basis in your .yml file. For example, the following:

```
# Logging settings.
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:

    # Overrides the levels of certain packages or files.
    "com.my.resources.User": OFF
```

Comment: Just a note, I had to write the `OFF` as `"OFF"`